# Division of labour: Capistrano vs Chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, chef-infra

Where do you draw the line between provisioning (Chef) and deployment (Capistrano)?

For example, take creating an nginx and unicorn setup for Rails. Installing nginx is Chef territory. But what about things like configuration files (`nginx.conf` and `unicorn_init.sh`) and unicorn config (`unicorn.rb`)--how do we divide this up?

The [official Capistrano 3 tutorial](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/) makes no mention of anything related to web or app server configuration.

So whose responsibility are these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is primarily opinion-based, but I'll answer anyway.

You draw the line wherever you want to draw the line.

Chef's main guiding philosophy is:

> You know your infrastructure best...

Some organizations use Chef to setup all the shared folders, links, assets, etc (like `cap deploy:setup` normally does). Some organizations **just** manage the infrastructure bits (users, permissions, software installed). And some organizations deploy entirely with Chef (no Capistrano at all).

It's really about your personal preferences and organizational culture.

Comment: Since we're giving opinions here :), I'll share mine. I've been in your shoes and I was lucky enough to not only experiment with all three approaches but also to operate production environments using them. First option is good if you don't need/want Chef to configure your apps (where you get environments, roles, etc). Third option is my favourite (all within Chef), and I'd recommend you go for that. You can gate your deployed versions per environment and it gives you a lot of freedom on how to manage everything. Only go for the second if you need push deployments and Chef for configs.

Comment: Having worked on and built {I,A,P,...}aaS systems, it’s important to have inversion of control and encapsulation, so Chef doesn’t get used like PHP often does... a tangle of crap. Or worse, a poorly-maintained Docker image. Instead, cap/rake can be used to deploy or configure app details. Chef is useful for cluster setups or almost anything else found in production in the real world.